# preg_match get first href from div

Tags: php, regex

I have this html data and I am trying to extract the first href value from the below div element.

```
<div>blah blah.
    <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
    <a href="http://www.example2.com">site</a>
</div>
```

I tried using this regex, but I can't figure out where I am going wrong?

```
preg_match('/<div>.*?<a.*"(.*)">/', $html, $match);
```

Could someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Have you considered using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) over regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Do not reinvent the wheel..

Use the right [tool](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for the job, not a regular expression.

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <div>blah blah.
         <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
         <a href="http://www.example2.com">site</a>
     </div>
');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$link  = $xpath->query("//div/a")->item(0);
echo $link->getAttribute('href'); //=> "http://www.example.com"
```

Comment: I never knew about this how would i load my html variable

Answer (score 0):

See the answer from [hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25008362/1616832) to use a more comfortable and precise way.

To do your request really with a regex instead you coude use such a approach:

```
<div>.*?<a[^>]+href="([^"]*)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_7AzIorkFOyN5FYi)

---

Still to say:

- Don't reinvent the wheel, like @hwnd said
- **avoid parsing HTML/XML & Co. with regex**

Answer (score 0):

```
    x="<div>blah blah.\n\t<a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>\n\t<a href="http://www.example2.com">site</a>\n</div>"
    import re
    pattern=re.compile(r".*? href=(\S+?)>.*?",re.DOTALL)
    y=pattern.match(x).groups()
    print y[0]
```

output:"http://www.example.com"

Answer (score -1):

You can try this
`preg_match('/<div>[^<]*?<a[^>]*\"([^>]*?)\"/', $html, $match);
 var_dump($match);`